# Retrieving the url anchor in a werkzeug request

Tags: anchor, flask, werkzeug

I have a DAV protocol that stores out-of-band data in the url anchor, e.g. the `ghi` in `DELETE /abc.def#ghi`. The server is a Flask application.

I can see the request come in on the wire via `tcpdump`, but when I look at the werkzeug Request object (such as url() or base_url()), all I get back is `/abc.def`. The `#ghi` has been stripped out.

Is there a method that returns this information, or do I have to subclass Request to handle this myself? If so, is there an example I can use as an inspiration?

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78132466/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same problem. Facebook authentication API returns the access token behind a hash appended into the redirection url. In the same way, Flask's request.url drops everything in the URL behind the hash sign.

I'm also using Flask so I think you can use my brute-force workaround using Javascript's window.location.href to get the full URL. Then, I just extracted the piece that I needed (the access token), put it into a redirection URL where I can pass the access token as an argument to the receiving view function. Here's the code:

```
@app.route('/app_response/<response>', methods=['GET'])
def app_response_code(response):
    return '''  <script type="text/javascript">
                var token = window.location.href.split("access_token=")[1]; 
                window.location = "/app_response_token/" + token;
            </script> '''

@app.route('/app_response_token/<token>/', methods=['GET'])
def app_response_token(token):
    return token
```

In case you manage(d) to do this within Werkzeug, I'm interested to know how.

Comment: @Mu Mind - There must be better and simpler solutions out there. That's for sure. If you know one, you'll be able to help more if you describe it here.

Comment: Interesting hack of a solution.. There must be a reason FB didn't just supply the access_token as GET param

Comment: same issue here. Damn you, Facebook. I'll just stick with the response_type=code

Comment: building on trungly's comment - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0 - the preferred method in this case is asking for a code and not a token, and then exchanging it for a token server-to-server

Answer (score 14):

From Wikipedia ([Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)) (don't have the time to find it in the RFC):

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the server

So Flask - or any other framework - doesn't have access to `#ghi`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [flask.url_for](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for) with the `_anchor` keyword argument:

```
url_for('abc.def', _anchor='ghi')
```

Comment: the question is about an incoming request not about generating an url with an anchor, so this is not applicable.