# Python Flask request.args.get unable to handle # request parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, flask, url-parameters

Anyone encounter this issue before? I'm unable to get the parameter value if the url have '#' in front.

http://localhost.com/auth?#state=111&access_token=2222

```
@app.route("/auth")
def loginAuth():
    state = request.args.get('state', '')
```

Comment: What about `.get('#state', '')`? Why is that hash on the URL at all? It indicates the start of a fragment, meaning the parameters section is over. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12682952/3001761; strictly, that URL doesn't have any query parameters.

Comment: Try set anchor (#state) to the form, and get this parameter in your function.

Answer (score 1):

The content after `#` is treated as anchor name. It won't be sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to deal with this situation. 
Yes '#' is URL fragment that won't be sent to the server

[Retrieving the url anchor in a werkzeug request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597603/retrieving-the-url-anchor-in-a-werkzeug-request)

Comment: so what is the workaround? in the link you provided there is no info about solution